# Git: Recovery of files possible after local remove before push?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu

I wanted to "clean" my git repo before pushing by removing every JPG file, so I entered:

```
find . | xargs rm *.png
```

in the git root and now **everything is delted**. Also my *.py files are deleted, but I do not know why? It is a Linux, Ubuntu machine. Is there any chance to recover my files? Maybe over my OS?

Comment: What does `git status` output?

Comment: "fatal: Not a it repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command you typed is plain wrong:

```
find .
```

This command outputs the name of every file and directory below `.`, including hidden files.

```
xargs
```

This command takes its input and runs the command given as its argument, feeding it one line at a time as an argument. Therefore, it will run `rm *.png <line1_from_find>`, then `rm *.png <line2_from_find>`, etc.

There is no safeguard like stop on errors, so if you let the command run completely, it unlinked all files and you know have an empty directory tree. And `git` will not help you, because it works by storing its metadata and current state within a `.git` directory at the root of the working directory. In which you just deleted all files.

So no, unless you made a copy, either manually or by pushing you state to some other place, it's probably gone, but see below. For future reference, here is the correct command to destroy all files ending in png:

```
find . -name '*.png' -delete
```

Optionnaly add `-type f` before the `-delete` if you may have directories ending in `.png`, to filter them out.

---

Okay, what now: it happens that `git` marks some of its internal state as read-only, which `rm` honors if you didn't use `rm -f` and you might be able to recover some data from that. Go to the `.git` directory at your working directory's root. It will contain a `objects` directory, and some files may have survived there.

Those files are raw compressed streams, you can see their content using that command:

```
zlib-flate -uncompress <path_to_the_file
```

(the zlib-flate command comes from qpdf package on ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Restoring by zlib-flate is not possible because the .git is completely empty.

Comment: @N8_Coder> I feel your pain. As a last resort you might try solutions from questions on askubuntu, such as [how to recover deleted files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files). Cross fingers and hope for the best, those tools always involve some luck.

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

for me the following worked:

```
$ git checkout -- name_of_deleted_directory
```

or

```
$ git checkout -- path_to_local_delected_directory
```

In my case, I deleted a directory by mistake and I didn't change any code in that directory but I had changed code in other directories of my git repo.